# Is it possible to search and update data in custom object from lightning web component without using apex class

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I have my lightning web component in opportunity layout and was storing data one the same using `recordId`, now I want to save that data on custom object.

I want to search in that custom data, and update if it's not present using recordId.

Can we do it without using `apex` classes?

Comment: Can you define custom data? is it same object or different object?

Comment: Its a custom object with 6 fields, with "opportunity_id" I want to save for searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot do it without an apex class, at minimum you will need to write code in trigger afterinsert/update of opportunity and create the record in the custom object.
I am asumming you are using lightning record* tags in the lightning web component, search and create in custom object is not possible without a custom apex class

Comment: Can create a custom object from lightning web component without `apex` class, only thing is I can't search through the record, will look to have apex class then. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Amol that's what I meant search and create is not possible without custom apex class

Comment: Sorry to point it out again we can insert in a custom object using `createRecord` passing `apiName`. Anyway created an apex class and code is moving now. Thanks for your help.